# jquery Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, exchangewebservices

The javascript I'm using works completely fine in firefox and ie but has this error when run on chrome and safari. I'm not entirely sure why it's failing.

```
        var response = asyncResult.value;
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");

        }
        else 
        {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
        }

        console.log(xmlDoc);
         var changeKey = xmlDoc.getElementsById("t:ItemId")[0].getAttribute("ChangeKey");
```

The console shows this message but outputs the xmlDoc just fine when I have it set to console.log()

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined        r.js 
soapToGetItemDataCallback    r.js
r.onreadystatechange    outlookwebapp-15.js:21 
$h.EwsRequest.$1x_1    outlookwebapp-15.js:21 
(anonymous function)   outlookwebapp-15.js:21
```

Comment: Does your `console.log(xmlDoc);` output the expected result?

Comment: yes, in both firefox and chrome

Comment: `getElementsById` is an invalid method, so this should fail in all browsers.  Perhaps it fails differently in Chrome and Safari than in IE and Firefox.

Comment: You're right, I actually copied and pasted the wrong version. At one point, someone suggested I try "byId". I actually originally had getElementsByTagName, which was the source of the original error. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Does using `getElementsByTagName` resolve your error?

Comment: No, the error persists in chrome. In Firefox changekey contains the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get the element by ID and using `[0]`, I guess you wanna `getElementsByTagName` because that the result is undefined, the code should be:

```
var changeKey = xmlDoc.getElementsById("t:ItemId").getAttribute("ChangeKey");
```

Or if `"t:ItemId"` is a collection:

```
 var changeKey = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("t:ItemId")[0].getAttribute("ChangeKey");
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually copied and pasted the wrong version. At one point, someone told me to try "byId". I actually originally had getElementsByTagName, which was the source of the original error.